# Adding Default WooCommerce Shipping to Dokan Vendor Dashboard

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

We are using [Dokan Multi-Vendor](https://wedevs.com/dokan/) plugin for WooCommerce and they have their own shipping module which is not the way we need to work the site.

The users can go into the back-end admin and are able to set the shipping correctly, however Dokan offers a simpler dashboard for the vendors which we want it to integrate with this as users can get confused.

The piece that we want to replicate across looks like the below in the WooCommerce back-end. Is there a hook or code that we are able to expose this in a custom dashboard?

[image]

I have found where I would like to add the code within `dokan/products/product-shipping-content.php`. The Vendor Dashboard looks like below and I want it to slot in to the Shipping and Tax section and to update the same

[image]

Talking to support from the plugin support is proving fruitless. Is there a way to display the default WooCommerce shipping methods, as shown in 1st image, within a custom vendor dashboard?

Comment: You might mention that Woocommerce Shipping per Product v2 is a paid plugin, not a free one. Or you could include the url where we can find the plugin... Might help getting your answer quicker.

Comment: @Klaassiek Yes, Per Product Shipping is a paid plugin (https://woocommerce.com/products/per-product-shipping/) I would have thought that it would be the same as any other shipping method to include in such a way, but I could be wrong. What else would you need to assist?

Comment: Since this is a paid plugin, why not contact their support? As far as I'm concerned, I can't help you. I am not going to pay for this plugin.

Comment: @Klaassiek I am in the process of discussing with the support of both plugins, with no solutions as of yet. Apologies for thinking this would be a forum that could help. I feel there is a generic way to display and edit shipping methods that I just don't know.

Even if we forget the paid plugin part, is there a way to display the default Woocommerce Weight/Dimension/Shipping Class? This would, in theory, apply across other shipping methods as well, both paid and unpaid.

Comment: If you ask me: currently your question is not likely to be answered. I would suggest to edit your post, so as to include the fact that this a paid plugin stuff, but certainly the question you just asked in the comment is worth including in your question. Many more of us can help you with a more generic question, than one about stuff we would have to pay for. :)

Comment: I have made the question more generic but not a huge amount is different from the spirit of the original question.

Comment: You can try to check in plugin the available `hooks`. For example: `do_action('some_method')`. It's help you modify the code.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to do this.

Install the dokan and woo commerce on your WordPress website. And for trial create a user in dokan and a trial product from that user. When we will add or edit the product from it, the dokan redirects us to the products in woo commerce where we can edit the product with the features we want. This is the whole solution!!!

See the video I made for this so that you will understand the solution perfectly :- https://vimeo.com/538650792

Comment: Thanks for that, but I did mention that we know users can go into the back-end admin and set up the shipping as required. We want it exposed on the Dokan vendor dashboard to make it simpler for the end user.